# Getting an error after running join

Tags: sql, powershell

I keep getting this error anytime i try to run the sql statement. What could be wrong?

> Ambiguous column name 'trafficCrashReportId'.

Comment: Your question is tagged "mysql", but the coding conventions are for SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `trafficCrashReportId` is present in both tables (`InvolvedVehicle` and `TrafficCrashReport`)

You'll need to specify which one should be selected... This example shows how to select the `trafficCrashReportId` from the `InvolvedVehicle` table.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select [trafficCrashReportId],
       InvolvedVehicle.involvedVehicleId,
      ,[assocVehNum]
      ,[wasStrikingVehicle]
from InvolvedVehicle INNER JOIN TrafficCrashReport ON InvolvedVehicle.trafficCrashReportId = TrafficCrashReport.trafficCrashReportId ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the column is in two tables, and the database doesn't know which to choose.  The best solution is to use table aliases and always qualify your column names:

```
select iv.[trafficCrashReportId], iv.[involvedVehicleId],
       tcr.[assocVehNum], tcr[wasStrikingVehicle]
from InvolvedVehicle iv INNER JOIN
     TrafficCrashReport tcr
     ON iv.trafficCrashReportId = tcr.trafficCrashReportId
Where tcr.addDate between '$Yesterday' AND '$TodayDate';" `
```

I am guessing which columns come from which tables.

Answer (score 0):

In your select statement you should be specific about which trafficCrashReportID you want, the one from InvolvedVehicle or the one from TrafficCrashReport.

Select InvolvedVehicle.trafficCrashReportId